# MySQL load data infile concatenate columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
mytable(`id` int, `text` varchar(255))
```

Also I have cvs-like file

```
1 hello word
2 this is a test
```

They are separated by space(or something else)

So can I use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load the file into the table? How can I do this..?

Comment: See [How to import text data in mysql with spaces?](http://corpocrat.com/2011/01/09/how-to-import-text-data-in-mysql-with-spaces/) for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go for 2 tables... One is the final, the other has 2 fields just as your CSV.

First solution, in file followed by 
    insert into table2 select concat(field1, field2) from table1

The other solution is to automate the solution 1 using a trigger. I'm not sure you can trigger something at the end, so trigger for each line added...